# Как последовательно в PDO вывести все строки в наборе циклом while? В данном коде выводится лишь только первая

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
  $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT Name, Text FROM users_cars WHERE Id_client=? AND id=?');
  
  $stmt->execute([$Id_client, $_POST['id']]);
     
  while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

    $user = array(
        'Name'=>$row['Name'],
        'Text'=>$row['Text']
    );

  $response['user'] = $user; 

  }
```

Comment: так может быть под такой запрос и подходит одна строка? вы бы проверили запрос где-либо

Comment: а вообще у вас tr есть, а td - нет. ещё один косяк... причём tr не закрыт

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `AND id=?` id - это PRIMARY KEY как бы обычно)) .... Алексей как у вас только нервов хватает)))

Comment: @Jour "это PRIMARY KEY как бы обычно"  --- обычно да, но у новичков бывает абсолютно всё, так что не удивлюсь что там может быть и "ispolzuemaya dlina"

Comment: Ну и здесь вообще непонятно что и где выводится. В цикле выводится только `<tr><tr>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name, Text FROM users_cars WHERE Id_client=? AND id=?");

  $stmt->execute([$Id_client, $_POST['id']]);

  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)) 
  { 
    $user = array(
        'Name'=>$row['name'],
        'Text'=>$row['Text']
   );
  $car['user'] = $user;    
  echo json_encode($car);   
  }   

    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]